# Add method no exist for global model

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and I have a global list in my class like:

```
public ProjectHistoryModel ProjectHistoryModel = new ProjectHistoryModel();
```

So in my method I try to use `Add` to add new items to this list like:

```
private void Enqueue()
{
    ProjectHistoryModel.Add
}
```

But it throws:

> 'ProjectHistoryModel' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no
>   extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ProjectHistoryModel' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: Can you post the code for your ProjectHistoryModel class?

Comment: You haven't made a list, you instantiated `ProjectHistoryModel`. That's not a list. Either you're looking for `List<ProjectHistoryModel>` or make a `List<T>` inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have defined is not a list, it is one instance of a class. Also the name you give the instance should not be the same as the actual class.

```
public List<ProjectHistoryModel> myHistoryModelList = new List<ProjectHistoryModel>()

public ProjectHistoryModel myHistoryModel = new ProjectHistoryModel();
// update the instance of the class with whatever values you want then add it to the list

myHistoryModelList.Add(myHistoryModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ProjectHistoryModel` is not a list.  If you want a "List" of `ProjectHistoryModel`s, then define it like this:

```
List<ProjectHistoryModel> ProjectHistoryModel = new List<ProjectHistoryModel>();
```